# Implementing Packed bubble Graph in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, graph-algorithm

How I can implement packed bubble graph in WinRT. I am trying to achieve  graph similar to attached image.[image: Packed Bubble Graph].

I tried for a similar implementation / sample for silverlight / Windows 8 in google, But didn't get any. Please anyone help me to achieve the same graph. My main issue is with implementing the logic correctly.

Comment: While it would be awesome to know, this is a really broad question amigo.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use a `WebView` in an XAML application.

Comment: This is a great question IMO, but you should consider changing the title to something like 'how to make a custom circle packing panel' or something as the only difficult bit is how to lay them out like that.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of project are you using? There's actually a way to do this in each kind of supported project.

For javascript you can use the Canvas element, which has easy 2D api's for drawing circles and text.

In C++ you can use the DirectX 2D api's to draw circles. In C# you can embed a DirectX panel into your xaml and then use DirectX to draw the circles.

In C# or C++ you can also solve this problem with *just* xaml, using a ListView with Canvas for an ItemsPanel, and Circle objects. Here is a blog post I found with a tutorial (except with rectangles):

http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/using-canvas-as-a-itempanel-template-in-listbox/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your need. If you are not averse to using JS + HTML in WinRT, d3.js should be very very useful

Example of packed bubble chart - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

http://d3js.org/

Hope this helps!